# How to use a custom field with add_rewrite_rule()?

Tags: custom-field, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm new to writing rewrite rules in WordPress and I want to make sure I'm not going about this the wrong way.

**My goal**: to use random numbers and letters as the URL ending for my custom post type `project` pages

My code below is what I've attempted so far ...

#### functions.php

```
// Create a random string and save it to the post for the URL ending
add_action('save_post','add_url_id');
function add_url_id( $id, $post ){
  $url_id = uniqid();

  if ( isset( $post->url_id ) ) {
    return;
  }
update_post_meta($id, 'url_id', $url_id );
}

// Let WordPress know about my custom query variable url_id
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_var' );
function add_query_var( $vars )
{
  $vars[] = 'url_id';
  return $vars;
}

// My rewrite rule to search for the custom post with the URL's same url_id
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);    
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^projects/([0-9a-z]+)/?',
    'index.php?post_type=project&url_id=$matches[1]',
    'top');
}
```

When I `var_dump` my post on the individual custom post pages, I can see that they do have a value in their `url_id` field. When I save this code and flush the permalinks cache, I find that I'm redirected to `http://example.com/projects/<string of numbers and letters>`, but I only see the homepage instead of the custom post. I'm guessing the issue has to do with no results being returned by my `url_id` variable, but I'm not sure why my query doesn't have any result since I do have posts with this field populated.

**Edit:**

This is what I'm currently seeing in the Rewrite Analyzer plugin
[image: rewrite results]

I'm also not finding that my URLs are being re-written at all at the moment, so I am not as far along as I had expected.

Comment: Your `url_id` may be a query variable now, but there's no logic attached to it. Those variables are passed into `WP_Query`, which doesn't have a `url_id` parameter. I take it this is a post meta field? ( a custom field? ) Where's the implementation of `uniqid` and how does it map on to posts?

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for taking a look. `url_id` is a custom field, but it is only created/updated in the function I've included above (does it need some setup elsewhere as well?). [`uniqid()` is a build in PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate the random string I'm looking for.

Comment: I would keep in mind then that this will involve a meta query, which are super expensive and do not scale. You will need to put that meta query inside the URL in your rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up taking another route based on Tom J Nowell's feedback that I would need an expensive meta query as part of my rewrite rules. I ended up changing the post's slug itself, which allows me to use WordPress's default functionality without any complicate rewrite rules. This is my code:

```
add_action('wp_insert_post_data','add_url_id', 50, 2);
function add_url_id( $post_data ){
  // Only set the random slug once and only for published posts
  $original_slug = sanitize_title( $post_data['post_title'] );
  if ( $post_data['post_name'] != $original_slug || $post_data['post_status'] != 'publish' ) {
    return;
  }

  // Generate random string
  $caps_letters = '';
  $caps_letters_len = 6;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $caps_letters_len; $i++) {
    $caps_letters .= chr( rand(65, 90) );
  }

  $numbers_and_lowercase = uniqid();
  $slug_length = strlen($caps_letters) + strlen($numbers_and_lowercase);
  $random_slug = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $slug_length; $i++) {
    if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
      $random_slug .= $numbers_and_lowercase[0];
      $numbers_and_lowercase = substr($numbers_and_lowercase, 1);
    } else {
      $random_slug .= $caps_letters[0];
      $caps_letters = substr($caps_letters, 1);
    }
  }

  $post_data['post_name'] = $random_slug;
  return $post_data;
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help on this! Now my posts have random URL endings, which was my original goal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'post_type_link' hook
 
and register post type 'project' with ('with_front' => true) parameters

```
 'rewrite' => array('slug' => $slug, "with_front" => true),
```

==================================or=====================================

```
add_rewrite_rule('^project/([0-9a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?project=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

====================================================================

```
  function post_type_link_hook($link, $post) {
    add_rewrite_tag('%url_id%','([^&]+)');
    if ('projects' == get_post_type($post)) {
        $urlId = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'url_id', true);

        //Lets go to get the parent cartoon-series name
        return str_replace('%url_id%', $urlId, $link);
    }
    return $link;
   }
 add_filter('post_type_link', 'post_type_link_hook', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I ended up taking a different approach on this (see my posted answer), but I appreciate your example of how to incorporate the meta post query.